# Silently install XAMPP using CMD on Win10 to non-default directory

Tags: xampp, silent-install

I am trying to install XAMPP silently on Windows 10 and I need to change the default installation directory.

I've used `Xampp-installer.exe --prefix D:\xampp`, but it's still being installed to `C:\xampp`.

Please advise me. Thank you.

`Xampp-installer.exe --help`

```powershell
Usage:

--help                                      Display the list of valid options

--version                                   Display product information

--unattendedmodeui <unattendedmodeui>       Unattended Mode UI
                                            Default: none
                                            Allowed: none minimal minimalWithDialogs

--optionfile <optionfile>                   Installation option file
                                            Default: 

--debuglevel <debuglevel>                   Debug information level of verbosity
                                            Default: 2
                                            Allowed: 0 1 2 3 4

--mode <mode>                               Installation mode
                                            Default: qt
                                            Allowed: qt win32 unattended

--debugtrace <debugtrace>                   Debug filename
                                            Default: 

--enable-components <enable-components>     Comma-separated list of components
                                            Default: xampp_server,xampp_apache,xampp_mysql,xampp_filezilla,xampp_mercury,xampp_tomcat,xampp_program_languages,xampp_php,xampp_perl,xampp_tools,xampp_phpmyadmin,xampp_webalizer,xampp_sendmail
                                            Allowed: xampp_mysql xampp_filezilla xampp_mercury xampp_tomcat xampp_perl xampp_phpmyadmin xampp_webalizer xampp_sendmail

--disable-components <disable-components>   Comma-separated list of components
                                            Default: 
                                            Allowed: xampp_mysql xampp_filezilla xampp_mercury xampp_tomcat xampp_perl xampp_phpmyadmin xampp_webalizer xampp_sendmail

--installer-language <installer-language>   Language selection
                                            Default: en
                                            Allowed: sq ar es_AR az eu pt_BR bg ca hr cs da nl en et fi fr de el he hu id it ja kk ko lv lt no fa pl pt ro ru sr zh_CN sk sl es sv th zh_TW tr tk va vi cy

--prefix <prefix>                           Select a folder
                                            Default: 

--launchapps <launchapps>                   Learn more about Bitnami for XAMPP
                                            Default: 1
```

Comment: What does `Xampp-installer.exe /?` || `Xampp-installer.exe -help` || `Xampp-installer.exe --help` return?

Comment: I added return msg. @JW0914

Comment: the .exe version does not allow the path change. Use the .zip or portable versions